# Can't set up keys - server times out

Tags: ros, installation, ros-hydro, ubuntu, ubuntu-trusty

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm installing ROS Indigo on a fairly fresh install of Ubuntu 14.04. I try to do step 1.3 and:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-key 0xB01FA116

Executing: gpg --ignore-time-conflict --no-options --no-default-keyring --homedir /tmp/tmp.iYA2SKI7oY --no-auto-check-trustdb --trust-model always --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --primary-keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/webupd8team-y-ppa-manager.gpg --keyserver hkp://pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-key 0xB01FA116

gpg: requesting key B01FA116 from hkp server pool.sks-keyservers.net

gpg: keyserver timed out
```

gpg: keyserver receive failed: keyserver error

Googling hasn't helped and previous answers on this forum are outdated. I tried to install it a week ago and I got the same error. Any ideas?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/227228/can%27t-set-up-keys---server-times-out/) by [djsw](https://answers.ros.org/users/25492/djsw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 153 on 2016-02-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Despite the fact that this issue persisted for a week, I tried again today and I did not receive this error. I assume it's the server's fault and there are just days at a time where you can't install ROS.

---

Originally posted by [djsw](https://answers.ros.org/users/25492/djsw/) with karma: 153 on 2016-02-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-02-24**:
Unfortunately ROS does not maintain the key servers, and this has been a know issue in the past: https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/roswiki/issues/140 . I've updated the tutorials to use the high-availability keyserver pool, which should help.